# Python counter to text file

Tags: python

So im trying to analyse a log file and extract information from it. 
One of the things im trying to do is extract a list of IP addresses that have more than 30 failed attempts. In this a failed attempt is one that starts with the line failed password for.

I have an idea for this that i wanted to try as i wasn't sure whether it will work.

If i use python to create a counter that looks for the keyword failed that i total and print out

This is what i have so far

```
failed_line=0
with open('blacklisttips.txt') as f2:
    lines= f1.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate (lines):
        if line.startswith(failed_line):
            f2.write(line)
            f2.write(lines[i+1])
```

Comment: So, why not try your idea and see what happens?

Comment: `I have an idea` <- please share your idea with us, so that we can show you how to get it to work

Comment: Please show us what you have achieved so far and ask a concise question about that code. Check here for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

So let's say your file looks like this:

```
failed password for 192.168.1.1
failed password for 192.168.1.2
...
more similar lines


import collections

prefix = failed password for
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    counts = collections.Counter(line.rsplit(" ",1)[1] for line in infile)
```